# How to slow down 240V AC bathroom fan

Tags: fan

I have a small toilet fan which is quite noisy and far too powerful for what we need. I'm looking for a solution where I could reduce AC 240V to AC 110-150V with minimum amount of components. Any transformer is out of question. Simply, no room for it. Initially, fan had a PIR sensor in the middle which was removed and now I have some space for components. 6x5cm and 2cm height. I know, it's not wise to use a resistor to reduce the voltage. Is there anything simple I could use in that space? I have more than basic experience in electronics but I didn't practice for 30 years. Sill, I understand components, diagrams, PCBs, multi-meters and can use a soldering gun. Anything I could get on ebay or assembly myself? Thank you all.

Comment: Look for SCR Dimming

Comment: Some folk prefer to have a noisy fan to save their embarrassment. Regard it as a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use capacitor in series. You are talking about bathroom fan, so I think this power is about 20...30W, it means current is about 0.1A, so to loose 100V you need reactance about 1kohm - so something between 1.8...3.3uF should be enough. Of course, DO NOT use electrolytic capacitors - only HV MKSE, MKS or polypropylene capacitors with breakdown voltage > 600V.

Comment: I  agree.  1.2uF MKS  cap to split a 20W fan with 10 VARs to half power.